# How would you find the nearest side of a rectangle from outside the rectangle

Tags: geometry

I am working on a side project and I'm in need of your help!

Given a rectangle of any rotation, and a point situated outside of said rectangle, how would you find the nearest side $a_1$, $b_2$?

note: I'm actually trying to find the final angle of an object that bounces against a rotated rectangle, I therefore believe that once I can identify which side the object is hitting(I know the angle of the rectangle) I should be able to find what the final angle is.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Shift the origin to one corner of the rectangle and then try using the sign of cross product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute, four times, the distance from your point to each of the four segments bounding the rectangle. And then return the min.

There are many web resources for point-to-segment distance. Here is one:
[Distance of a Point to a Ray or Segment](http://geomalgorithms.com/a02-_lines.html)

---

[image]

---